# How to set scrollTop on each tab in a Multipage UserForm?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've figured out how to set the ScrollTop in `UserForm_Initialize()` however I can't work out how you can set an event on each time a user flicks between a tab/page in a Multipage.

Does MS Word  VBA not have a similar function to `UserForm_Initialize()` or `UserForm_Activate()` for when a tab/page is changed?

My issue is even though I have ScrollTop = 0 in `UserForm_Initialize()`, when the user swaps to a new tab/page the focus is changed to focus on the top control (textbox) and the ScrollTop is no longer 0. So I need to reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

Word VBA has a multipage function you can use to determine when a user enters a new page/tab.

For example:
`Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
  Me.ScrollTop = 0
 End Sub`

You would add this to your UserForm module.